# zedgraph does not draw a graph

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I have a realtime data and i want to draw it with using zedgraph. I write these codes but it does not draw a graph.

```
   public void AddPointToGraph(double x, double y)
   {

         GraphPane gp = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

         PointPairList pairlist1 = new PointPairList();
         pairlist.Add(x,y);

         LineItem linus = gp.AddCurve("Label", pairlist, Color.Red , SymbolType.None);
         linus.Symbol.Type = SymbolType.None;
         linus.Line.Width = 1.5f;


         zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.IsFontsScaled = false;
         zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
    }
```

I call `AddPointToGraph()` func in time function and give them x and y double values but nothing seems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RollingPointPairList](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_RollingPointPairList.htm) instead of PointPairList , there's an example available for [real time plot](http://goorman.free.fr/ZedGraph/zedgraph.org/wiki/index3061.html?title=Display_Dynamic_or_Real-Time_Data)